# Xmodmap doesnt remember my settings

Tags: bash, keyboard, monitor

I need to map one of my key to other key and I do it with the following command:

xmodmap -e "keycode 94 = a"

but I need to do it everytime I restart my PC. Is there any other way? Why won't it remember what I did? Its the same for xrandr --output LVDS-1 --off, I want to remove my laptop's monitor and I have to do it everytime, its annoying as hell

Comment: `xmodmap` configures the X server, which is restarted afresh every time you reboot or login. To reapply _both_ settings, wrap them in a `bash` script, in invoke it from a `.desktop` file in `~/.config/autostart`. `.desktop` files have a special format, so look at other `.desktop` files (`locate .desktop`)